# How long ClaimedIdentifier can be?

Tags: dotnetopenauth

**Hello,**

I want to save ClaimedIdentifier in database.

How long it can be?

Probably, 255 characters is ok?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An openid.claimed_id is limited only by the maximum length of a URL, which technically can reach at least 2K -- I'm not sure just how large it can be.

However, even the unreasonably long OpenIDs actually seen in the wild don't exceed 255 characters, so that seems like a reasonable practical limit to me.